# Bean Validation and error messages at .properties file

Tags: jsf, glassfish, bean-validation

i am working on a JSF Projekt with Glassfish. My validation works well but i dont become a custom error message.

```
//Class = User, package = devteam
@NotEmpty @Pattern(".+@.+\\.[a-z]+")
private String emailAddress;
```

My ValidationMessages.properties is in the WEB-INF folder with this content:

```
devteam.User.emailAddress=Invalid e-mail address
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are having two problems here. First, the location of the *ValidationMessages.properties* file. It has to be in the root of the classpath, so move it into *WEB-INF/classes*
Your second problems are the message keys. The default message key for the Pattern constraint for example is *{javax.validation.constraints.Pattern.message}*. In your case you want to specify the message parameter in the *@Pattern* annotation:

```
@Pattern(regexp=".+@.+\\.[a-z]+", message="{devteam.User.emailAddress}")
```

Comment: I'm not using tomcat, so I can't add the properties file to WEB-INF/classes. Instead I'm doing a scala project in eclipse, but I can't get it to use the properties file. Where would you add the properties file in a standard eclipse project?

Comment: @Marius, the archive root directory

Comment: @Hardy I've created another question about it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15748884/bval-validationmessages-properties-in-scala-eclipse-project

Answer (score 1):

You should put the file in the root, then

```
devteam.User.emailAddress[Pattern] = "Your message here"
```

notice [Pattern] to specify the message to output when the Pattern has a constraint violation.
this makes it easier to maintain in my opinion vs having the messages like

```
@Patterh(regexp ="xx", message = "your message here")
```

for every setter