# How get localized messages from properties file with error in bindingResult?

Tags: spring, validation, spring-mvc, binding, spring-data

Hi I have some `Ajax Forms`, where I use an `Async POST` to send data to server...

If `BindingResult` has an error I want show a message in view, after the input field, to explain the error, so this is my **method** in my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public Map<String, String> create(@Valid MyClass myClass, BindingResult bindingResult, Model uiModel, 
        HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse response, Locale locale) {

        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST);
            Map<String, String> errorFields = new HashMap<String, String>();
            for(FieldError fieldError : bindingResult.getFieldErrors()){
                errorFields.put(fieldError.getField(), fieldError.getDefaultMessage());
            }
            return errorFields;
        }

        uiModel.asMap().clear();

        myService.create(personale);

    return null;
}
```

And it works, but `fieldError.getDefaultMessage()` return an **English** message, but I want return a **Localized** message..

I know that I can do in this way:

```
@NotNull(message="{myMessage}")
private Field field;
```

But I wouldn't specify the localized message to each field, maybe can I use `message.properties` file??

Is it possible??

Thank you!

### EDIT

I readed this: [another question about my problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5786582/how-to-use-annotation-validation-in-spring-with-error-message-gotten-from-proper?rq=1), but I can't get from messagges...

Comment: Hello Teo, did you manage to resolve the issue? If so, please share.

Comment: No, I don't find a solution yet.. So @Cԃաԃ if you have any suggestion I accept it :)

Comment: lol :) I don't know the solution too. But I will work on it through this coming week, so if i'll find the solution I'll let you know.

Comment: Hi Teo, I didn't find the solution... :(

Comment: Someone please find a solution! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I faced the same problem and i could solve it on this way:

1. Define your properties messages under src (mybasename_locale.properties)
2. Include these elements on your config file (dispatcher-servlet.xml) in order to initialize properly the Spring's classes l18n related

   ```
   <bean id="messageSource"
   class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
   <property name="basename">
       <value>mybasename</value>
   </property>
   ```

   ```
   <bean id="localeResolver"
   class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver">
   <property name="defaultLocale">
       <value>es</value>
   </property>
   ```
3. In your controller, get a reference to your ResourceBundleMessageSource bean.

   ```
   @Autowired
   private ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource;
   ```
4. Then, you can get the error message through getMessage method getMessage(MessageSourceResolvable arg0, Locale arg1)

   ```
   @ResponseBody
   @PostMapping(path = "/login")        
   public ResponseEntity<?> login(@Valid @RequestBody User user, BindingResult result) {
       if (result.hasErrors()) {
           System.out.println(messageSource.getMessage(result.getFieldError(), LocaleContextHolder.getLocale()));
       }

       // other stuff
   }
   ```

Comment: I just had to override the LocaleResolver Bean and then it worked.