# How supply translated custom error message for JSR 303 bean validation?

Tags: jsf-2, bean-validation

My question is basically same as  [Custom validation message for bean validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8048710/custom-validation-message-for-bean-validation). However, I can't fix the problem.

The bean class:

```
public class PersonalInfoBean {
    @Size(min=5, max=55, message="{invalid_name}")
    String name;
    ...
}
```

I created Messages.properties in a package in the src folder of Eclipse project.

```
invalid_name=Please enter a valid name
```

I registered the file in faces-config.xml:

```
<application>
    <message-bundle>com.webage.survey.Messages</message-bundle>
</application>
```

The facelet file has:

```
<h:inputText value="#{personalInfo.name}" id="name"/> <h:message for="name" style="color: red" /><br/>
```

When I submit the form, I see only {invalid_name} as error message and not "Please enter a valid name".

I tested this with JBoss 6 and WebSphere 8 with the same result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're mixing [JSR 303 Bean Validation framework](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/edr/jsr303/index.html) with JSF builtin validation. JSR 303 Bean Validation framework is not part of JSF framework. It's an entirely standalone validation framework for which JSF just happens to have integration support.

You need to specify the JSR 303 Bean Validation messages in a different properties file instead with the *exact* filename of `ValidationMessages.properties`, which can be localized with `ValidationMessages_xx_XX.properties` files. Those files have to be placed in the root of the classpath.

You do not need to register it in `faces-config.xml`. The `<message-bundle>` is only used for JSF builtin converters and validators such as `required="true"`, `<f:validateRegex>`, `<f:convertDateTime>`, etc.

Comment: It worked! I had to put ValidationMessages.properties in the default (root) package.