# Bval ValidationMessages.properties in scala eclipse project

Tags: eclipse, scala, sbt, bean-validation

I have a scala project (based around unfiltered and jetty) which uses bval. I've tried everything I can think of to get custom validation messages to load from a properties file, but it just doesn't work. I have a scala class like this:

```
class AddName{
    @NotEmpty(message = "{firstName.notEmpty}")
    var firstName: String = ""
    @NotEmpty(message = "{lastName.notEmpty}")
    var lastName: String = ""
}
```

and a ValidationMessages.properties file containing the following:

```
firstName.notEmpty=enter a first name
lastName.notEmpty=enter a last name
```

But the output from the validation results is `{firstName.notEmpty}` not matter what I try.

I have tried placing the properties file in the project root, in a resource folder which is exported to the classpath by the run configurations. I've also tried placing it in the `target/scala-2.9.1/classes` folder and then running the project with `sbt compile`.

Comment: I am not a Scala expert, so what is happening here exactly? You have Scale class which gets transformed into a Java class right? And you are using Hibernate Validator? Have you tried turning on debug log?

Comment: I am not using Hibernate, just [bval](http://bval.apache.org/)