# How to globally set the message for a Hibernate Validation constraint?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-validator

I have the following class that I'm trying to validate via Hibernate:

```
public class LoginForm
{
    @NotBlank(message = "{myCustomMessage}")
    private String user;

    @NotBlank(message = "{myCustomMessage}")
    private String pw;

   //....
}
```

This works fine and my custom message is correctly displayed for `NotBlank`, however if I have to specify the `(message = "{myCustomMessage}")` line for every single constraint, for every single member, in every single class, its going to become very repetitive.

Is there a way to globally set this message, so it doesn't have to be specified individually for every member? I.e so it will, by default, fetch `myCustomMessage` for `@NotBlank`? (And for all the other constraints that I specify it for).

Edit: So if I rename the message key from `myCustomMessage` to `org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotBlank.message` , then I no longer need to specify the `(message..)` line. However, I'd still prefer if it could be made to work with `myCustomMessage` globally.

Comment: Please look at this previous answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2235544/bean-validation-and-error-messages-at-properties-file

Comment: @Romski That doesn't answer my question

Comment: Sorry, just re-read your question and I see your issue. Other than the solution in your edit, I'm not aware of anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already found out, the only way would be to specify a value for the default key `org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotBlank.message`. You also could define your own `NotBlank` constraint which specifies the value you want as default value for the `message` attribute, but I would not really recommend that.